# How to redirect to Home page on refresh using Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-router-guards

I am using Angular CLI to build app. I have configured routes as shown below:

```
const routes: Routes = [
 {path: 'Home', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'About', component: AboutUsComponent},
  { path: '**', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'Home' }
];
```

I have a requirement that on refresh of the page I need to redirect to Home path. 
**Note:** I have tried doing it with guards but failed to achieve desired result. Please help me out with the steps.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is that your trying to do? on which condition it should navigate to home copmonent?

Comment: Explain whoever gave you this requirement that it's a bad requirement. Users expect the currrent page to refresh when hitting the refresh button, because that's what it's for. It shouldn't navigate elsewhere.

Comment: If it is browser refresh it should be done on a server / load balancer side

Comment: What have you done with the guard?

Comment: It is done through guard only.You need to check on what condition it should redirect to home page and write that logic in guard.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. It requirement I have. @Aravind When ever user refresh it should got to home page. JB Nizet yup I know but As per the requirement we have written separate js file and when user refresh particular page it breaks as home page js is not loaded.

Comment: @pritesh Yup I tried with guards but I am not getting exact way to know when refresh happens in guard

Answer (score 0):

you can add a redirect in your app.component to your home page.
app.component load once and will be load again in a new refresh.

Comment: I was able to it using guards. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is applicable to Ang7
In app.component.ts,

```
<strong>import { Location } from '@angular/common'
```

then in ngOnInit() within the same file add:

```
if(location.pathname != "/"){location.replace("/")}
```

Assuming you have Route setup and your home URL path is "/"